# TikZ Stop and Check!

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment

In my materials, I'd like students to have to verify at certain points with a teacher that they are ready to move onto harder materials.

I'd like my students to see something like this:

[image]

Maybe the stop sign would be a little smaller and I don't really care about the font, btw.

Here's the effort I have made to make that happen. Two things to change:

1. How do I write "STOP" in white inside the TikZ diagram?
2. How do I align the picture vertically?

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\STOP}
{\tikz{
 \draw[line width=1.2pt,scale=0.4,baseline=-0.5ex]
  (22.5:1)--(3*22.5:1)--(5*22.5:1)--(7*22.5:1)--(9*22.5:1)--(11*22.5:1)--(13*22.5:1)--(15*22.5:1)--cycle;
 \fill[scale=0.32,baseline=-0.5ex]
  (22.5:1)--(3*22.5:1)--(5*22.5:1)--(7*22.5:1)--(9*22.5:1)--(11*22.5:1)--(13*22.5:1)--(15*22.5:1)--cycle;}
 Check this section with a teacher before moving on.}


\begin{document}

\STOP

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

To add the text, you just need `\node[font=\tiny\bfseries\sffamily]{STOP};`. The vertical alignment can be adjusted with the `baseline` option to the `\tikz` command. I needed to increase the size a bit to make the text fit.

A completely different approach is to use a symbol from `marvosym`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{marvosym,graphicx}

\newcommand{\STOPP}
{\begin{center}
\tikz[baseline=-1ex]{
 \draw[line width=1.2pt,scale=0.6,baseline=-0.5ex]
  (22.5:1)--(3*22.5:1)--(5*22.5:1)--(7*22.5:1)--(9*22.5:1)--(11*22.5:1)--(13*22.5:1)--(15*22.5:1)--cycle;
 \fill[scale=0.53,baseline=-0.5ex]
  (22.5:1)--(3*22.5:1)--(5*22.5:1)--(7*22.5:1)--(9*22.5:1)--(11*22.5:1)--(13*22.5:1)--(15*22.5:1)--cycle;
\node [white,font=\small\bfseries\sffamily] {STOP};}
 Check this section with a teacher before moving on.
\end{center}}

\newcommand{\STOP}{
\begin{center}
\scalebox{2}{\raisebox{-1.7ex}{\Huge\Stopsign}} Check this section with a teacher before moving on.
\end{center}}
\begin{document}
\STOP\bigskip

\STOPP
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic! It did not even occur to me to use text inside of a `\node`.

Comment: How does one hear about something like the `marvosym` package?

Comment: @WeCanLearnAnything Well, that is sort of what `\node`s are for - placing text in `tikzpicture`s. I found the symbol from `marvosym` in the [comprehensive symbol list](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

TikZ has a package known as `shapes.geometric`, by which we can easily draw regular polygons like this with adding labels inside. I drew two of them; one is not filled (the outer one) and the other is filled black and has the sign text.

`\parbox`es naturally center their content vertically, so I used a `\parbox` of the same width as the sign to automatically center the sign relative to the surrounding text.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\newcommand{\STOP}{%
\parbox{1.33cm}{%
\tikz{%
 \node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=8, minimum width=1.33cm, draw, line width=2pt](n1){};
  \node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=8, minimum width=1.2cm, draw=white,fill=black,label=center:\color{white}{\bfseries\sffamily STOP}]at(n1){};
 }} Check this section with a teacher before moving on.%
}%


\begin{document}

Some text \STOP

\end{document}
```

Also, if you prefer the `marvosym` approach, I would use the same `\parbox` to vertically center the sign with the surrounding text. Only package `calc` will also be required to calculate width of the sign as this :

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{marvosym,graphicx,calc}

\newcommand{\STOP}{%
\parbox{\widthof{\Huge\Stopsign}}{\Huge\Stopsign} Check this section with a teacher before moving on.}

\begin{document}
\STOP
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thank you! A question about your first set of code: Why did you type `regular polygon, regular polygon` instead of just typing it once?

Comment: @WeCanLearnAnything Look again, it's `regular polygon, regular polygon sides=8`. First say that the node shape should be a regular polygon, then specify that it should have 8 sides.

Answer (score 2):

TikZ actually provides an example of a STOP! sign in the manual using the `chamfered rectangle` shape, which can be adapted as follows:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]% modified from manual page 736
  \node (stop) [chamfered rectangle, text=white, font=\bfseries\sffamily, fill, double=white, double distance=.2ex, draw, very thick, inner ysep=2ex, inner xsep=0pt, chamfered rectangle xsep=1ex, chamfered rectangle ysep=1ex] {STOP};
  \node [right=of stop, anchor=west] {Check this section with a teacher before moving on.};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: STOP]

For convenience, this can be transformed into a command `\stophere[<optional instructions>]` which will use the text from the MWE in the question by default, or other instructions if specified.

I've also allowed a little vertical space before and after the stop sign which is probably what you'd want in a worksheet, for example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,kantlipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc,positioning}
\newcommand*\stophere[1][Check this section with a teacher before moving on.]{%
  \medskip\par
  \tikz[font=\sffamily]{% modified from manual page 736
    \node (stop) [chamfered rectangle, text=white, font=\bfseries\sffamily, fill, double=white, double distance=.2ex, draw, very thick, inner ysep=2ex, inner xsep=0pt, chamfered rectangle xsep=1ex, chamfered rectangle ysep=1ex] {STOP};
    \node [right=of stop, anchor=west] {#1};
  }%
  \medskip\par
}

\begin{document}
\kant[1]
\stophere
\kant[2]
\stophere[Complete Exercise 2 before reading the next section.]
\kant[3]
\end{document}
```

[image: STOP. Make sure you understand Kant's point before proceeding!]

Comment: Awesome, thank you! How did you hear about the `shapes.misc` and `positioning` packages and how to use them? Some of the code there seemed pretty complex, e.g. `\node (stop) [chamfered rectangle, text=white, font=\bfseries\sffamily, fill, double=white, double distance=.2ex, draw, very thick, inner ysep=2ex, inner xsep=0pt, chamfered rectangle xsep=1ex, chamfered rectangle ysep=1ex] {STOP};`

Comment: @WeCanLearnAnything They are not packages per se, but TIkZ libraries. Their use is described in [the manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf). If you search the manual for each of those keywords (`chamfered rectangle`, `double`, etc.) you will find descriptions. (Useful tip about the manual: when things like that are used in examples, they are also hyperlinks to the place where they are defined.  So if you find an example with the `double distance` key, you can click it, and it will take you to the definition.)

Comment: @WeCanLearnAnything I just remembered that TikZ had some libraries with shapes for signs and looked in its manual. As Torbjørn mentioned, these are not separate packages but libraries extending core TikZ and part of the TikZ package. The `chamfered rectangle...` options are covered in the manual section on that shape. The other options are just standard options for TikZ nodes: colours, lines, inner space between node contents and lines, font etc. Each one is quite simple and covered in the manual. As Torbjørn also said, you can find many of them via the example stop sign (page ref. as above).

Answer (score 1):

This should work, also: (in xelatex or lualatex)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\begin{document}

\faHandStopO
\end{document}
```

Comment: `fontawesome` works with `pdflatex`, too. (Probably `latex`, as well? Not sure.)